# How to resetup Animator?

Tags: android, animation, drawing

I am using a single Animator instance to smoothly scroll view down or right. First I set it up with common parameters within my custom View implementation:

```
private ObjectAnimator animator = new ObjectAnimator();
{
    animator.setTarget(this);
    animator.setDuration(moveDuration);
}
```

then I am using two methods to move down and right

```
public void moveRight() {

    if( animator.isRunning() ) animator.end();

    animator.setPropertyName("scrollX");
    animator.setIntValues(getScrollX(), getScrollX() + cellWidth);
    animator.start();
}

public void moveDown() {

    if( animator.isRunning() ) animator.end();

    animator.setPropertyName("scrollY");
    animator.setIntValues(getScrollY(), getScrollY() + cellHeight);
    animator.start();
}
```

I found, that only first called method works correctly. Another one works wrong as if first ran method left some traces inside animator object.

How to remove these traces and to reprogram animator from scrolling right to down and vice versa?

Comment: code provided is not helpful..

Comment: Show how are u using this code.. where you call the methods?

Comment: I call this method from 2 buttons, via their `onClick()` handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. For some reason, using setPropertyName() a second time doesn't seem to clear out the previous property and/or values.

Using setProperty() instead fixes this, e.g.:

```
Property<View, Float> mTranslationXProperty = Property.of(View.class, 
   Float.class, "translationX");
Property<View, Float> mScaleXProperty = Property.of(View.class, 
   Float.class, "scaleX");
...
animator.setProperty(mTranslationXProperty);
animator.setFloatValues(500f, 0f); 
animator.start();
...
animator.setProperty(mScaleXProperty);
animator.setFloatValues(1f, 0f); 
animator.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reset values using the code below:

```
final AnimatorSet animate = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.anim_move);
List<Animator> animations = animate.getChildAnimations();
for (int i = 0; i < animations.size(); i++) {
    ObjectAnimator animator = (ObjectAnimator) animations.get(i);
    if (animator.getPropertyName().contentEquals("y")) {
        animator.setFloatValues(0f, 500f);
    }
}
animate.setTarget(starlightImageView);
animate.start();
```